# How to make Chinese characters smaller using XeCJK

Tags: fontsize, xecjk

I'm using XeCJK to edit an article that contains some Chinese characters. Compared to English letters, Chinese characters are significantly bigger. How can Chinese characters be made smaller? Could someone please help me to solve this problem? Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[10.5pt, leqno,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\usepackage[CJKspace]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Light}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Mono}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Etiam lobortis 白日依山尽 facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent im-
perdiet mi nec ante. Donec 黄河入海流 ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`  never use either of those packages with xetex

Comment: Usually we set Chinese characters to be a little bigger than latin upper case letters but a little smaller than the latin lower case letters which take up three lines. It's the normal taste for most Chinese people. And if you write a document whose main language is Chinese then the visual advantage would come out.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and I've deleted the irrelevant packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the XeCJK [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf) on page 7, you can use `\defaultCJKfontfeatures` with a `Scale` option. Note that this command should be given *before* you load the CJK fonts.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10.5pt, leqno,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\usepackage[CJKspace]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Mono}
\defaultCJKfontfeatures{Scale=0.6}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Etiam lobortis 白日依山尽 facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent im-
perdiet mi nec ante. Donec 黄河入海流 ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel...
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note also that I removed the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages as they are not relevant for XeLaTeX.

Comment: The 10.5pt option does nothing. Why not `Scale=MatchUppercase`?

Comment: @egreg `MatchUppercase` works too (and may be a good default) but with a numerical scale value you have more control over how big or small the characters should be of course.

Comment: @egreg It may be because Chinese characters have been set to be such size in 10.5pt, i.e., Chinese characters in 10.5pt are a little bigger than latin upper case letters in 10.5pt. It's related to the font files.

Comment: Hi Marijin, egreg, and M. Logic, I have followed your suggestions and revised the codes. The outcome is good. Thank you so much for the advices and discussions.